# Which DataTemplate is selected based on DataType if multiple match

Tags: wpf, xaml

Given the following VM class hierarchy

```
public abstract class BaseClass {}
public class SubClass : BaseClass {}
public class OtherSubClass : BaseClass {}
```

I want to use a ContentPresenter to select a DataTemplate based on the type of the DataContext. It should select one template for SubClass, and a different one for all other subclasses of BaseClass. I use the following implementation:

```
<ContentPresenter>
  <ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BaseClass}">
    ...
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SubClass}">
    ...
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

This works, but I am not sure how fool-prove this implementation is.

What are the rules by which the DataTemplate is selected based on the DataType? I searched a lot but was unable to find the answer. I could imagine that the data template with the most specific matching type is used, but I would feel better if I had proof for this (and it is not related to something else like the order of DataTemplates or WPF's mood).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code of `FrameworkElement.FindTemplateResourceInternal`, WPF will search resource for `DataTemplate` by track back the data item's inheritance.

[image]